# Flutter: Error Element 'List<Column>' can't be assigned to the list type '<Widget>'

Tags: android, list, flutter, for-loop, widget

My code contains fixed widget `//1` and `//4` inside `Column` and I want to generate list of widget in between it. Originally, I code the widget manually (refer `//2`).
However, since I will be having a list of `BulletList` and `SurahCard` widgets that I want to generate, I want to use either `for` loop or `List.generate` (refer `//3`).

However, I'm getting this error:

```
Element 'List<Column>' can't be assigned to the list type '<Widget>'
```

Appreciate if anybody can shed some light on how to fix this?

```
import ...

class ReciteSurah extends StatelessWidget {

  static const String id = 'recite_surah_screen';

  int pageNumber;
  int surahNumber;
  late Surah surah;
  late String surahName;
  List<int> surahNumberList;

  ReciteSurah({required this.surahNumberList, required this.surahNumber, required this.pageNumber}){
    surah = SurahHelper().getSurah(surahNumber: surahNumber);
    surahName = surah.nameMS;
  }
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 96.0),

        child: Column(
          children: [

            //1 - This widget is fixed
        H2(text: '$pageNumber. BACA SURAH AL-FATIHAH & SURAH LAIN ATAU BEBERAPA AYAT LAIN'),

            //2 - Manually calling the BulletList & SurahCard Widget
            BulletList(lines:const [
              'Baca surah al-Fatihah:',
            ] ),
            SurahCard(surahNumber: 1),
            BulletList(lines: [
              'Baca surah $surahName:',
            ] ),
            SurahCard(surahNumber: surahNumber),

            //3 - Programatically generate List of BulletList & SurahCard Widget
          List.generate(surahList.length, (index){
            int curSurahNumber = surahNumberList[index];
            Surah curSurah = SurahHelper().getSurah(surahNumber: curSurahNumber);
            return Column(
              children: [
                BulletList(lines: [
                  'Baca surah ${curSurah.nameMS}:',
                ] ),
                SurahCard(surahNumber: curSurahNumber),
              ],
            );
          },
          ),

            //4 - This widget is fixed
            P(text: 'Anda juga boleh membaca surah pilihan sendiri.'),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like for the existing code `//1` `//2` and `//4`:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `...` [Spread Operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) to add the list of `widgets` into your Column.

```dart
...List.generate(
              surahList.length,
              (index) {
                int curSurahNumber = surahNumberList[index];
                Surah curSurah =
                    SurahHelper().getSurah(surahNumber: curSurahNumber);
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    BulletList(lines: [
                      'Baca surah ${curSurah.nameMS}:',
                    ] ),
                    SurahCard(surahNumber: ${curSurahNumber}),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

> Spread Operator are used for inserting multiple elements in a collection, In your case, it is `Column`'s children (which is `List<Widget>`) in which you want to add one more `List<Widget>`.

Comment: Thank you @ibhavikmakwana for solving this for me. I'm new to the `...` Spread Operator

Comment: You can learn more about the dart lang features over here.https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour